# PHP Xpath multiple nodes

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I would like to extract both attributes BODY and TYPE from the following xml and output the TYPE as div class and body as text.

For example:

```
foreach (...) {
echo "<div class='$type_value'>$body_value</div>"
}
```

**My XML:**

```
<smses>
<sms body='something' type='1' address='1234'>
<sms body='something' type='2' address='12345'>
<sms body='something' type='2' address='1234'>
</smses>
```

**My code (so far extracting only one attribute - body):**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('xml/sms.xml');

$path = new Domxpath($doc);

$num = $_POST["sel"];

$result = $path->query("//smses/sms[@address='$num']/@body");

foreach($result as $res)
{
echo "<div id='sms'>".$res->textContent.'</div><br/><br/>';
}
```

Comment: Get the matching `sms` elements (rather than their `body` attribute), and use `getAttribute()` within the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `/@body` from the XPath so that you select the actual `<sms>` element, using that you can get the `type` attribute and its body text into the `<div>`:

```
$result = $path->query("//smses/sms[@address='$num']");

foreach($result as $res)
{
    echo "<div id='sms' class='" . $res->getAttribute("type") . "'>". $res->getAttribute("body").'</div><br/><br/>';
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/vRf7GifJ)

Comment: Do i also have to change textContent to getAttribute("body")?